# How to increase size of spaces in indentation?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My indentation are too thin. But I also don't want to use more than 2 spaces for indentation. Is there a way to increase the size?

Current view,

[image]

Expected View,

[image]

Comment: Are you using any formatter extension like prettier or beautify? or just the default vscode formatter?

Comment: @tHeSiD No, I am not using any extension for formatting.

Comment: you are using a proportional font, use a monospace font. How do you get these two screen shots?

Comment: @rioV8, In first screenshot "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Mono", In second one, "editor.fontFamily": "".

Comment: @rioV8, Sorry but can you tell how to use proportional fonts?

Comment: look at the column alignment of the characters in picture 1, it is a proportional font that is used. You set the font in picture 2 to empty string? This will use the default "Courier New` font (??)

Comment: I added an answer, please check, also if you are using a language extension, it might have its own setting sometimes, what lang is this?

Comment: @tHeSiD, Thank you for the answer. I have already up-voted it but I cannot accept it as I mentioned in the question from the beginning that I don't want to use more than 2 space for indentation. I am using Dart language in Flutter framework.

Comment: Ohh, I misread your question. My bad. In that case you can experiment with wider monospace fonts like Courier Prime Code or Monaco. etc

Comment: potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76920712/11107541

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't using any formatter type extension

You can set your indentation easily by selecting the indenting option in the status bar.

[image: Indenting status bar]

[image: Indenting options]

and then select the size you want.

If you want to globally have the same settings.

add these values to your `settings.json`

```
    "editor.tabSize": 4, //4 = 4 spaces
    "editor.detectIndentation": true, // this will auto detect whether your file is using spaces or tabs to indent. 
    "editor.insertSpaces": true, // Insert spaces when pressing Tab. This setting is overridden based on the file contents when #editor.detectIndentation# is on.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Stretchy Spaces](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kylepaulsen.stretchy-spaces) extension.

> Do you hate your project's indentation level and have a hard time reading your code? Then just stretch it to be what you want! You can expand or contract your indentation using this extension.

> Note: This only works on files that are indented using spaces. If a
> file is indented using tabs, vscode can already change your tab size!
> It's built into the editor!

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Comment: None - just found it today while trying to solve this issue for myself.