# Separate local vs repo indentation

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can we have different code indentation on repo vs local editor?

For example some of the devs want more spaces :) and I'm wondering if the editor can display lets say 2 spaces as 4 spaces without actually affecting the committed code. (The code remains with 2 space indentation, but locally to some of the devs visually to look as 4 spaces or whatever)

Something like devs having their own local preferences without those settings affecting the commits.

Comment: The minority should just suck it up, trying to dynamically adjust it will cause endless issues. Make everyone configure ClangFormat so they don't forget (perhaps check formatting in Git hooks, if this remains an issue).

Comment: If you are using git for version control then you can probably use git filters to achieve this. Like, every time you pull the file locally you filter it to apply your own indentation and every time you commit/push it applies the dev indentation.

Answer (score 1):

#### If you want to take a git route

Write [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)- a [`post-checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_checkout) hook that calls a script to convert to the local width, a [`pre-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_commit) hook to convert to the remote width, and a [`post-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_commit) hook that converts back to the local width. Use your scripting language of choice (just add the appropriate shebang). I leave the choice of exactly what software you use to perform the indentation change up to you. There are plenty of options out there (some not-super-cross-platform (Ex. `sed`/`awk`), but ubiquitous on specific platforms, and some that are more suited to specific programming language ecosystems (Ex. Prettier, clang-tidy, etc.)), and I'm not ready to prescribe one.

#### If you want to take a VS Code route

rioV8 has an extension [`rioj7.vscode-indentWhitespace`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-indentWhitespace) (which I have no affiliation with) that seems well suited to this (but I think *only if* you want the local indentation to be *wider* than the remote indentation). It uses VS Code's [decoration mechanism](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions) to insert "fake" spaces into the rendering (hence why it can only go wider and not narrower locally). See [its contributed settings](https://github.com/rioj7/vscode-indentWhiteSpace#settings): `indentWhitespace.space.enlargement` and `indentWhitespace.space.positionDecorator`.

Alternatively, (and) this would be slightly less automated than the git route, you could probably combine the approach I suggest in [In VS Code, How do I format a document (.cpp) so that it converts indentation with N spaces to indentation with M spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75954165/11107541) (using VS Code commands to convert indentation to tabs, change the indentation width to the desired width, then convert indentation back to spaces) with rioV8's [`rioj7.commandOnAllFiles`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.commandOnAllFiles) extension and the [`ryuta46.multi-command`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) (which I have no affiliation with) to achieve this.

There's also another extension that you might find useful if you're indenting with spaces: [`kylepaulsen.stretchy-spaces`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kylepaulsen.stretchy-spaces) (I have no affiliation with this extension).

#### Misc notes

Also consider using tabs for indentation. It solves the problem of people wanting to have different indentation sizes/widths, since editors usually have a setting that lets you choose how wide tab characters are. Ex. in VS Code, it's the `editor.tabSize` setting. Also related to tab and space conversions in VS Code: [How can I convert indentation between spaces and tabs for all files in a workspace in a single action?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51068247/11107541)