# Make current VSCode indentation *look* like another

Tags: visual-studio-code, rendering, indentation

I am working in a repository that, among some formatting rules, applies 2 spaces indentation to js files, but I prefer longer indentations like 4 spaces.

In VSCode, we can convert the indentation size, but doing this VSCode modifies the whole document making it not format compliant with the current rules of the repo.

I would like to know if there is an option/work around to make the current indentation (2 spaces) to ***look*** like another (4 spaces) ***without*** actually modifying the document so I can have the desired rendered spaces without messing up the code rules.

Something like "rendering" the spaces/tabs longer or shorter according to the current and wanted indentation.

Comment: you can try an extension I wrote: [Indent Whitespace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-indentWhitespace)

Comment: I distinctly remember seeing (and even answering) a question just like this in recent months, but somehow cannot find that question or my answer... maybe my memory is malfunctioning... ah nvm. my answer got deleted. duplicate question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76920712/11107541

Comment: That's it guys, thank you!